# emacs: standard input is not a tty

Tags: windows, emacs, git-bash

I want to use emacs in git bash, but when I run:

> emacs -nw file.c

It gives me some error saying:

> **emacs: standard input is not a tty**

However When I run the same command to open a file in cmd(Windows Terminal) it works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that `emacs.exe` (Windows native) would talk to the console TTY, not mingW tty, you can try:

```
winpty emacs  -nw file.c
```

That would be compatible with your git bash session.

As noted by [daveloyall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1981415/daveloyall) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62780553/emacs-standard-input-is-not-a-tty/62787621#comment126108842_62787621):

> For msys2 users, install `winpty` first with:
>
> ```
> $ pacman -S msys/winpty
> ```

For [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) users, winpty.exe is already there in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`.

Comment: msys2 users: `$ pacman -S msys/winpty`

Comment: @daveloyall Good point, thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.